# View has no attribute 'as_view' in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have a just basic view:

```
class MyView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
```

and in my urlconf

```
url(r'^my-view/$', MyView.as_view(), name='my_view'),
```

but I get the AttributeError `type object 'MyView' has no attribute 'as_view'`.

What causes this?

Comment: Looks like it may be due to a naming conflict.  Can you confirm that you haven't defined "View" or "MyView" somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. I am importing `View` as `from django.views.generic.base import View` and there is no problem if I inherit from `TemplateView` instead of `View`.

Comment: Its an Import problem I think. Check if you are importing the class or the name of the file. @Jamgreen